# siunitx "S" column, "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" latex error

Tags: tables, siunitx

What is causing the "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" message?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newlength\colwidth
\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of actual }
\label{tab:Comput_time}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=1.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{13}{c}{Frameworks without and with feature engineering and optimization modules}\\
 %\multicolumn{5}{c}{Models with feature engineering and optimization modules}
\cmidrule{1-14}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ELM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{CNN} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{SVM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{SDPSO-ELM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{F-RBF-CNN} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{SSA-SVM-CS}&
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{FA-HELF}\\
\cmidrule{1-2}\cmidrule{3-4}\cmidrule{5-6}\cmidrule{7-8}\cmidrule{9-10}\cmidrule{11-12}\cmidrule{13-14}
 &
 & {CT} & {MAPE}
 & {CT} & {MAPE}
 & {CT} & {MAPE}
 & {CT} & {MAPE}
 & {CT} & {MAPE}
 & {CT} & {MAPE}
 & {CT} & {MAPE} \\
 &
 & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)}
 & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)}
 & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)}
 & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)}
 & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)}
 & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)}
 & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)} \\
\midrule
170 & 2.25 & 185 & 2.20 & 115 & 2.98  & 242 & 1.65 & 512 & 0.99 & 355 & 0.89  & 285 & 0.42\\ [1ex]

\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions -- the first two are essential to get your code to compile correctly, the remaining ones are mainly in the 'nice to know' category:

- You're currently defining the `tabular*` environment to consist of a *single column*, yet you then proceed to refer to up to 14 columns. Something can't be right...

  Try replacing `S[table-format=1.4]` with `*{7}{S[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=1.2]}`, i.e., 7 pairs of `S[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=1.2]`, for a total of 14 columns.
- You also need to get rid of two unnecessary and counterproductive `&` symbols before `{CT}` and `{(\si{\second})}`, respectively.
- I would center the first row *across all 14* columns, not just columns 2-14.
- You seem to have various unneeded `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\cmidrule` statements. Get rid of them.
- The `\centering` directive isn't needed, as the `tabular*` environment takes up the full width of the textblock. I'd get rid of it.
- Don't use a `table*` environment unless your document uses a multicolumn setup. Use a `table` environment instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}%, makecell}
%\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
%\renewcommand\theadgape{}
%\newlength\colwidth % doesn't seem to be needed either
\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Evaluation of actual (what?)}
\label{tab:Comput_time}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  *{7}{S[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=1.2]} }
%\toprule
\multicolumn{14}{c}{Frameworks without and with feature engineering and optimization modules}\\
 %\multicolumn{5}{c}{Models with feature engineering and optimization modules}
%%%%%\cmidrule{1-14}
\midrule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{ELM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{CNN} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{SVM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{SDPSO-ELM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{F-RBF-CNN} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{SSA-SVM-CS}&
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{FA-HELF}\\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}  \cmidrule{5-6} \cmidrule{7-8}
\cmidrule{9-10}\cmidrule{11-12}\cmidrule{13-14}
  {CT} & {MAPE} & {CT} & {MAPE} & {CT} & {MAPE} & 
  {CT} & {MAPE} & {CT} & {MAPE} & {CT} & {MAPE} & {CT} & {MAPE} \\
  {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)} & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)} & 
  {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)} & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)} & 
  {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)} & {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)} & 
  {(\si{\second})} & {(\%)} \\
\midrule
  170 & 2.25 & 185 & 2.20 & 115 & 2.98  & 242 & 1.65 & 
  512 & 0.99 & 355 & 0.89  & 285 & 0.42\\ %%%%[1ex]
%%%%\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. JazakAllah@ Mico. Now it works

Comment: @GhulamHafeez - You're most welcome!